# Java's named capturing groups and trying to see if they are optional

Tags: java, regex

I am currently using named capturing groups in a regex applied to a URL.  The client feeds in the regex, but I need to get:

- list of capturing group names
- which of the names are required
- which of the names are optional

Currently, I am cheating and translate `{id}` or `{someVar}` to a capture group and everything is required.  Now however, because of add/edit, some urls are like this

- `/postadd`
- `/postedit/someIdHere`

so the regex is ONE route matching both.  I believe it would look something like this

- `/postadd|/postedit/(?<id>[^/]+)`

I would really really really prefer not to use a regex on the regex to find out if it is optional(as code like that is hard to read and reverse engineer).  Is there any way instead to list the capturing groups and find out if it's optional or not?

Comment: So, to clarify, you consider a named-capturing group to be "optional" if there's some way that the regex can match without that subgroup being matched?

Comment: yes.  ie. if I had /postedit/(?<id>.*) and that was it, I consider it required.

Comment: *Is there any way instead to list the capturing groups and find out if it's optional or not?*  - no, because a regex pattern is compiled into an internal program, and there is no access to that program after it is compiled. Also, a group is made optional both with `?` and `*` and `??` and `*?` and `*+`...

Comment: oh shucks, yeah, (?<id>.*) ended up being optional :(.  Anyway to make that a required match with named capturing group?

Comment: hmm @WiktorStribiżew at the same time, this ended up being required /public/(?<path>[^/]+) as the url would not match unless you put something.  Basically, /public/ does 'not' match while /public/anythinghere matches.  When using .* however, /public/ does match.

Comment: @DeanHiller: You described the regex behavior correctly. What do you need?

Comment: I was only hoping to be able to list out optional named capturing groups vs. required ones(ie. won't match unless it is there).  It sounds like that may not be so easy to do at this time as there is no api exposed from what I can tell.  (I was hoping I was wrong).